# VC dimension & number of support vectors

Tags: machine-learning, svm

How is the VC dimension of a support-vector machine related to its number of support vectors? Is there a formula relating these two quantities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*VC dimension (for Vapnik Chervonenkis dimension) (Vapnik and Chervonenkis (1968, 1971), Vapnik (1979)) measures the capacity of a hypothesis space. Capacity is a measure of complexity and measures the expressive power, richness or flexibility of a set of functions by assessing how wiggly its members can be. Sewell (2006)*

In other words, it shows the maximum sample number that can be shattered perfectly by the model.

On the other hand, support vectors are the points that define the hyperplane. It may be somehow related to the VC dimension, but no well-proved mapping between the two is established.

Actually the actual VC dimension is not easy to obtained for a non-linear classifier (for linear it is n+1). Here is [one paper called Ellipsoidal Kernel Machines](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~jebara/papers/ekm.pdf) that tried to estimate the dimension of svm with the gap tolerate classifier, yet I think it's far from a well-defined relation as you wish to see.

Comment: My question exactly concerns your last point: do you have a reference or more details regarding the lack of a connection between the VC dimension and the number of support vectors?

Comment: Note 3 of Cortes-Vapnik 1995 states, "In the support-vectors learning algorithm the complexity of the construction does not depend on the dimensionality of the feature space, but on the number of support vectors." This strongly suggests that there is a well-defined relation between the VC dimension and the number of support vectors of a given support-vector machine. http://image.diku.dk/imagecanon/material/cortes_vapnik95.pdf

Comment: actually the actual VC dimension is not easy to obtained for a non-linear classifier (for linear it is n+1). Here is one paper that tried to estimate the dimension of svm with the gap tolerate classifier, yet i think it's far from a well-defined relation as you wish: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~jebara/papers/ekm.pdf

Comment: Thanks much for the reference. Suppose we build a standard soft-margin SVM using the kernel trick, and embed the data into a Hilbert space H. Therefore the non-linear classifier is actually a linear classifier in feature space H. Would the VC dimension of the SVM be equal to dim(H)+1 ?

Comment: actually, EKM tries to estimate the VC dimension reduction once you introduce the well fitted mahalanobis distance to the problem. The VC dimension of gap tolerant classifier has been proven years before. and as to "VC dimension, but no well-proved mapping between the two is established." - it is only partially true, for hard margin SVM there is a tight generalization bound of expected number of SV divided by number of samples, which shows the tight bound on VC dimension.

Comment: @lennon310, thanks so much. I hadn't realized VC dimension of SVMs was so straightforward. Now I see why it's very difficult to relate VC dimension & number of support vectors. The former is related to the dimension of the feature space (which depends only on the kernel), and the latter depends in a complicated fashion upon the data.

Comment: @lennon310 Could you point to any reference where it is shown that the VC dimension of a linear SVM is dim(H)+1 please?